# How can I create Image Gallery in html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a website that is done by html. So the home file is index.html. Now I need to insert an image gallery inside that html file. The gallery will be H:300px and W:600px, with two arrows one for left sliding the other for right sliding.

I'm newbie doing an image gallery inside an html file. So I need to know how to do that and if there is any tutorial for doing that or any way to help me doing that.

Comment: I am not being rude! Please google your question. LOTS of tutorials for what you want. This question is too vague for us.

Comment: like @Iznoggood said... to find you a tutorial, anyone here would likely have to google it themselves

Comment: thanks a lot. I did that but I got the image slider ready to be downloaded, I cannot find any that can describe it in details. Please do you know any link?

Comment: http://www.dynamicwp.net/articles-and-tutorials/top-20-jquery-slideshow-and-image-gallery-tutorials/

Comment: @Iznogood, thanks a lot for your help. Actually, I do my best to google it but I couldn't find any thing useful. I know there are a lot of websites talking abut that, but I could not find it, may be because I don't write a good query in search box of google, or may be because of something else. So I came to here for asking if someone knows something that can help me. Anyway thanks for all and for who give it -3!

Comment: @HTMLMan google: "image gallery tutorial html"

Comment: @Iznogood thanks, I'm sorry that I come here. I will always use google, no need to ask a question here and the answer is a vague question. Be sure, I don't like to ask people and I do my best to solve the problem.

Comment: @HTMLMan here is a great place to ask questions. Just read the faq first. You are more then welcomed here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are really newbie, you can try this : http://wowslider.com
or that http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/gallery.html

Have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

[Fotorama](http://fotoramajs.com) is a very good JS image gallery slider.